# Tensorflow 2.3.1 mutliGPU NaN loss values

Tags: gpu, tensorflow2.0, multi-gpu

There are few issues reported on that matter but still no luck with finding answer. To simplyfy here is short code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
print(tf.__version__)
# 2.3.1
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(([1.], [1.])).repeat(100).batch(10)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=4)
```

after execution I'm getting

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1')

Epoch 1/4
INFO:tensorflow:batch_all_reduce: 2 all-reduces with algorithm = nccl, num_packs = 1
INFO:tensorflow:batch_all_reduce: 2 all-reduces with algorithm = nccl, num_packs = 1
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 93ms/step - loss: 807385211185512087331799040.0000
Epoch 2/4
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 93ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/4
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 93ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 4/4
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 93ms/step - loss: nan
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step - loss: nan
```

Without **strategy** output seems normal and loss is calculating normally

```
Epoch 1/4
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 4.2581
Epoch 2/4
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.8821
Epoch 3/4
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.8319
Epoch 4/4
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3677
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2284
```

As runtime environment I'm using tensorflow containter `nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.10-tf2-py3` from Nvidia GPU Cloud - so it is up to date and compatible with all kind of drivers. I also tried with newer version `20.12-tf2-py3`

Answer (score 1):

Had an identically looking problem with multi-GPU training on tensorflow 2.4 with 2x AMD GPU. Meanwhile I managed to fix my system. With the fixed system your code snippet runs correctly (does not produce NaN).

It turned out that the Variable data transfer between GPU silently failed. You could check if you have the same problem by executing

```
import tensorflow as tf

v = tf.Variable(1.0)

with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    print(v)
```

With failing device-to-device transfer it did not give expected result `<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>`. If your output also has mismatching numpy value there is a problem with your system.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, even though it doesn't fixes the issue at hand, it points towards the actual cause of the behavior (Failing device-to-device transfer). 
My system is a 2x NVIDIA GPU with SLI enabled, and everything works until I enable Intel VMX on the BIOS. Then the device-to-device transfer starts to fail.
Did you ever found a fix? Since our systems are different, I'm not sure it will help me, but Google returns nothing when looking for this weird case.